# Accessing Firebase push() child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm slowly getting into Firebase but have what is probably a stupid question. If I am adding children to a reference using push(), how do I retrieve/delete them if I don't save the generated push ID?

For example, take this root:

```
var ref = https://myaccount.firebaseio.com/player
```

And if I write a new entry to /player:

```
var new_player= ref.push({
    name:"User",
    country:"United States"
  })
```

Firebase generates a push ID for that:

```
https://myaccount.firebaseio.com/player/-JxgQCQsSLU0dQuwX0j-
```

which contains the information I pushed. Now lets say I want to retrieve or remove that player? Should I store the generated ID as a child of itself using .key() and .set()?:

```
//this will get -JxgQCQsSLU0dQuwX0j-
var _newPlayerKey = new_player.key(); 


//updates the record I just created
var update_player = ref.set({
    name:"User",
    country:"United States",
    ref: _newPlayerKey
  })
```

I don't see how else to access that object by it's generated ID... is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: As an alternative to accessing records by key (`child()`), you can use Firebase queries: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: How can I query it if there's a part of the path that is unknown? For example, I can order by query but without calling .key() I don't know which path to go into... I'm not asking this to be rude I'm honestly asking :)

Comment: To get users based  on their name: `new Firebase('https://myaccount.firebaseio.com/player/').orderByChild('name').equalTo('User').on(...`. But storing the key as a named property inside the same object never makes sense. Then you can just do `new Firebase('https://myaccount.firebaseio.com/player/').child(key)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing that can't use the key() method, it should be adequate in almost all cases i.e.

```
playersRef.limit(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {    
   var player = "<p>"+ snapshot.val().name +" <button data-value='"+snapshot.key()+"'>Delete</button></p>";      
   $(player).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));      
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to non-relational databases so this seems like a strange concept to me... if it's an accepted practice I'm more than happy to do it :) Thanks for the feedback!!!